# C++ forward reference in IOS Project (forward references to 'enum' type)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using a SDK in one of my projects and when adding in the libraries etc, I get an error from this line of code, which is from inside a .h file. I cannot change the .m since its not available to me. Its inside .a (lib)

```
-(enum scanDeviceID)ID;
```

And the error message is:

Semantic Issue
ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types

Are there any compilier/build setting that I can modify to make this work?

Failing that, I know very little C++, is there something on the line of code I can change to make it work?

Comment: Please post some code around that. What you're trying to do? A cast?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `enum` keyword? Having it where you do isn't valid C++. You might be thinking of the C syntax for identifying structs.

Comment: That is a line of code from a .h that is causing the compiler to stop. I cannot see the .m since it is compiled into a .a (library)

Comment: Is "-(enum scanDeviceID)ID;" the full line of code?!

Comment: Adriano: yes, it's a valid Objective-C method declaration for a method named 'ID' that takes no parameters and returns an "enum scanDeviceID".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of code says that this method returns an element that's named in the `scanDeviceID` enum.  The problem is that the compiler doesn't see a declaration of that enum.  Somewhere in a .h file you should have that declaration.  Importing the file should fix it.

Comment: You put me on the right track. I have that import, but in the .mm file instead of the .h file. As I was using the enum as a property declared there, the compiler still didn´t like that. Moving the import to .h solved the problem to me. Point for you, sir!